# jQuery and php registration script not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mobile

I'm developing a user registration and login for a an app using `jQuery` and `PHP`. I am having trouble inserting a record into my members database. When I click submit I'm getting the "Not Registered" alert., it just takes me back to the registration page.

My `jQuery` handle for the submit button and the `HTML`:

```
$('#regsubmit').click(function(){
         $.post("register.php",{reguser: $("#reguser").val(), fname: $("#fname").val(),lname: $("#lname").val(),regpass: $("#regpass").val(), regemail: $("#regemail").val()},function(data){
             if(data == true){
                alert("Registered"); 
             }else{
                alert("Not Registered"); 
             }
             });
      });

<div data-role="content">
<div data-role="collapsible"><h2>Register</h2>
   <form action="" method="post" id="registrationform">
   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="fname">First name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value=""  />
      <div id="fnamecheck"></div>
    </div>
       <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value=""  />
      <div id="lnamecheck"></div>
    </div>
       <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="regemail">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="regemail" id="regemail" value=""  />
      <div id="emailcheck"></div>
    </div>
 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="reguser">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="reguser" id="reguser" value="" />
      <div id="usernamecheck"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="regpass">Password:</label>
      <input name="regpass" type="password" id="regpass" value="">
      <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="confirmregpass">Confirm Password:</label>
      <input name="confirmregpass" type="password" id="confirmregpass" value=""></div>
    </div>
    <input name="regsubmit" type="submit" id="regsubmit" value="Register" data-icon="check" data-theme="a"/>
   </form>
       </div>
```

And my register.php:

```
<?php
$MYSQL_SERVER =  "localhost";
$MYSQL_USER = "root";
$MYSQL_PASSWORD = "password";

        $db = mysql_connect($MYSQL_SERVER, $MYSQL_USER, $MYSQL_PASSWORD ) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("hedonsof_conflict") or die(mysql_error());

        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['regemail'];
        $reguser = $_POST['reguser'];
        $regpass = $_POST['regpass'];
        //Username check
        $usercheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='".$reguser."'");
        if(empty($fname)||empty($lname)||empty($email)||empty($reguser)||empty($regpass)){
            if(empty($fname)){
                $errors[] = "Missing first name.";
            }
            if(empty($lname)){
                $errors[]= "Missing last name.";
            }
            if(empty($email)){
                $errors[]= "Missing email.";
            }
            if(empty($reguser)){
                $errors[]= "Missing user name.";
            }
            if(empty($regpass)){
                $errors[] = "Missing password.";
            }
        }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $errors = "Not a valid eail address.";
        }else{
            $fname = strip_tags($fname);
            $fname = stripslashes($fname);
            $fname = trim($fname);

            $lname = strip_tags($lname);
            $lname = stripslashes($lname);
            $lname = trim($lname);

            $email = strip_tags($email);
            $email = stripslashes($email);
            $email = trim($email);

            $reguser = strip_tags($reguser);
            $reguser = stripslashes($reguser);
            $reguser = trim($reguser);

            $regpass = strip_tags($regpass);
            $regpass = stripslashes($regpass);
            $regpass = trim($regpass);

            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, fname, lname, password, email) VALUES('$reguser','$fname','$lname','$regpass','$email)") or die(mysql_error());

                $msg = "Thanks for Registering.";
                if($msg){
                echo true;
            }else{
                $errors[] = "Sorry error with database at this time.";  
                echo $errors;
            }
        }
?>
```

EDIT:

```
<?php
$MYSQL_SERVER =  "localhost";
$MYSQL_USER = "root";
$MYSQL_PASSWORD = "password";

$db = mysql_connect($MYSQL_SERVER, $MYSQL_USER, $MYSQL_PASSWORD ) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("hedonsof_conflict") or die(mysql_error());

        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['regemail'];
        $reguser = $_POST['reguser'];
        $regpass = $_POST['regpass'];
        $errors[] = "";

        //Username check
        $usercheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='".$reguser."'");

            if(empty($fname)){
                $errors[] = "Missing first name.";
            }
            if(empty($lname)){
                $errors[]= "Missing last name.";
            }
            if(empty($email)){
                $errors[]= "Missing email.";
            }
            if(empty($reguser)){
                $errors[]= "Missing user name.";
            }
            if(empty($regpass)){
                $errors[] = "Missing password.";
            }
   //     }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
     //       $errors = "Not a valid email address.";
        else{
            $fname = strip_tags($fname);
            $fname = stripslashes($fname);
            $fname = trim($fname);
            //$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($fname);

            $lname = strip_tags($lname);
            $lname = stripslashes($lname);
            $lname = trim($lname);
            //$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($lname);

            $email = strip_tags($email);
            $email = stripslashes($email);
            $email = trim($email);
            //$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($email);

            $reguser = strip_tags($reguser);
            $reguser = stripslashes($reguser);
            $reguser = trim($reguser);
            //$reguser = mysqli_real_escape_string($reguser);

            $regpass = strip_tags($regpass);
            $regpass = stripslashes($regpass);
            $regpass = trim($regpass);
            //$regpass = mysqli_real_escape_string($regpass);

            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, fname, lname, password, email) VALUES('$reguser','$fname','$lname','$regpass','$email')") or die(mysql_error());

                $msg = "Thanks for Registering.";
                if($msg){
                echo "true";
            }else{
                $errors[] = "Sorry error with database at this time.";  
                echo "false";
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: I believe that `data` isn't a Boolean with value `true` but actually a string. So I recommend two things (if you're not gonna use JSON) change the `echo` line in php to `echo "true";` and in Javascript check with `if(data == "true")`

Comment: I think @Adnan is right on this one, data is a string response, unless you tell jQuery otherwise, you should echo it as a string as well, check your output from the server in the console.

Comment: Thanks I made this change but problem still exists.

Comment: In your javascript ajax response function, do a `console.log(data)` and tell us what it says.

Comment: There is a barrage of issues with your PHP. 1)Use mysqli_real_escape_string to escape variable before running qwueries with them. 2)You don't need one main if for errors loop as you're already checking each value 3)Where do you initialize erros array? 4) You don't have closing quotation mar after $email in your INSERT query. 5)Invalid email doesn't mean other fields aren't empty and vice versa. 6)Despite running a query, you don't actually check whether new username is already in the db or not. It doesn't actually prevent entering duplicate value. I can go on...

Comment: Thanks AR. I got it working. Thanks for pointing out my error checking redundancy. I initialized $errors and added the ' after $email. I'm now trying to get mysqli_real_escape_string working, but without that added yet it works. I'll post my edited code.

Comment: I check for existing username in my jQuery but am also going to add it to my php

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#regsubmit').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

      $.post("register.php",{reguser: $("#reguser").val(), fname: $("#fname").val(),lname: $("#lname").val(),regpass: $("#regpass").val(), regemail: $("#regemail").val()},function(data){
         if(data == true){
            alert("Registered"); 
         }else{
            alert("Not Registered"); 
         }
      });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: @RapsFan1981 have you tried to data in to alert and what it is returning from the code?

Comment: Ya data didn't seem to be returning anything, but I got it fixed now.